# dmi: Firmware registration failed

Tags: boot-issues, kernel, driver

I have installed Gentoo kernel 4.14.y from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux. dmesg shows the following errors

```
...
...
[    0.182547] dmi: Firmware registration failed.
...
...
[    2.224843] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
[    2.270109] random: crng init done
[    3.483868] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
[    4.751858] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
...
...
[    6.120869] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
[    8.168627] cgroup: cgroup2: unknown option "nsdelegate"
[    8.631640] udevd[657]: starting version 3.2.5
[    8.688998] udevd[657]: specified group 'i2c' unknown
[    8.689131] udevd[657]: specified group 'spi' unknown
[    8.689254] udevd[657]: specified group 'gpio' unknown
...
...
[   15.996362] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   18.018711] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   20.956254] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   20.958169] Segment Routing with IPv6
[   26.082743] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
```

How can I fix them and update to the latest stable kernel?

--**progress**--

`specified group *** unknown` in solved by `groupadd ***`

Comment: what do you mean by `installed` ? .... what process did you use? .... why don't you post your question here? ....  https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what distribution you are using but with *Raspbian* you get the latest stable kernel from its repository. You have to ensure that the sources.list contains the right repositories:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Then do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then you will have the latest stable kernel that also fits to the loadable modules and overlays. You should not get any error messages about this, assumed you are using *Raspbian*.